# Cmake "expanding" (?) shared library, duplicate linking issue

Tags: c++, cmake

Preamble:
This issue is compounded by some not-great practices and outdated software. It's enterprise and there isn't much I can do about it in the short-term.

I'm using Cmake 2.8 and am trying to link up some libraries in the following configuration:

```
root CMakeLists.txt:

add_subdirectory(dir_a)
add_subdirectory(dir_b)
add_subdirectory(dir_tests)

set(myLibs A B)
set(thirdPartyLibs C D E) #link_directories and such already set elsewhere
add_library(AB SHARED)
target_link_libraries(
  AB
  "-Wl,--whole-archive"
  myLibs
  "-Wl,--no-whole-archive"
  thirdPartyLibs)
```

```
dir_a CMakeLists.txt:

add_library(A STATIC <sources for a>)
```

```
dir_b CMakeLists.txt:

add_library(B STATIC <sources for B>)
```

```
dir_tests CMakeLists.txt:

add_executable(Z zsource.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Z AB) #AB is the shared object
add_test(Z Z)
```

When I look at the linker input (within CMakeFiles directory) for Z, it's doing something like this:

```
... c++ <flags> ... zsource.o -o Z <link directories> -rdynamic libAB.so -Wl--whole-archive libA.a libB.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive <third party libs>
```

The problem is that the static libraries `libA.a` and `libB.a` contain globals. These globals are checked for uniqueness, and if a global is found to be duplicated then this is judged a serious problem. When linking `Z`, this is what happens. I suspect that inclusion of `libAB.so`, `libA.a` and `libB.a` is duplicating the globals.

How do I avoid this behaviour? I've tried adding various combinations of PUBLIC, PRIVATE, INTERFACE to `target_link_libraries` for AB and Z and it doesn't have the effect I want - either the same error exists, or symbols become unresolved.

Comment: `PRIVATE` should work, please show a [mre] of what you've tried and what errors you encountered

Answer (score 0):

Use `target_link_options` with `SHELL:` prefix, see documentation.

```
target_link_options(
  "SHELL:-Wl,--whole-archive $<TARGET_FILE:A> $<TARGET_FILE:B> -Wl,--no-whole-archive"
)
```

I like:

```
add_library(A ...)
target_link_options(A INTERFACE
   "SHELL:-Wl,--whole-archive $<TARGET_FILE:A> -Wl,--no-whole-archive"
)
add_library(B ...)
target_link_options(B INTERFACE
   "SHELL:-Wl,--whole-archive $<TARGET_FILE:B> -Wl,--no-whole-archive"
)

target_link_libraries(exe PUBLIC A B)  # just works
```

* I think the best is to use `$<SHELL_PATH:$<TARGET_FILE:A>>`